# How the get the parent element of a FCE in Fluid Powered TYPO3

Tags: fedext

Is there a possiblity to get the parent element of the current element.

Fx: I have a two column FCE and in this two column FCE I will place a custom image element. For performance reasones I would like to render the image only as big as necessary. If the special image elememt is in a two column element the image can be smaller as it must be outside of the two column element.

Until now I did not find a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Id of parent record is always stored in `{record.tx_flux_parent}` - however, you may need to manually transfer the `{record}` variable since this does not happen automatically.