# Getting parent / nested Flux CE within fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid

Is it possible to get the parent CE type/name within a nested CE?
I have a Custom Flux Grid CE with two columns, inside the columns you can place another CE. Now I would like to detect if the child is inside the grid, if yes do this and that.

Comment: what construction or extension do you use to stack CEs into each other? you might add tags regarding extensions and versions.

Comment: "Custom Grid CE"

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the technology used to store the relation between parent and child, you could always go for the FLUIDTEMPLATE parameter `dataProcessing`.

Either create a variable `children` or `parent` via a DatabaseQueryProcessor like that

```
tt_content.mycontent.20 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
tt_content.mycontent.20 {
   file = EXT:site_default/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentObjects/MyContent.html

   dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
   dataProcessing.10 {
      # regular if syntax
      if.isTrue.field = records

      # the table name from which the data is fetched from
      # + stdWrap
      table = tt_address

      # All properties from .select can be used directly
      # + stdWrap
      colPos = 1
      pidInList = 13,14

      # The target variable to be handed to the ContentObject again, can
      # be used in Fluid e.g. to iterate over the objects. defaults to
      # "records" when not defined
      # + stdWrap
      as = myrecords

      # The fetched records can also be processed by DataProcessors.
      # All configured processors are applied to every row of the result.
      dataProcessing {
         10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
         10 {
            references.fieldName = image
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can use all the parameters of `select` for that DataProcessor and each of them can be modified using stdWrap properties. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select.html

Just make sure to replace `as = myrecords` with the desired variable name and then access this variable directly from within your Fluid template. You can use `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` to get an overview of the available variables.

Taken from these docs https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#dataprocessing

Additionally you might want to take a look at this video https://www.twitch.tv/videos/380759921 to get an idea what dataProcessing is about.

Comment: Ok I think I missed a small detail, I use flux for my CEs. Don't know if your method (which I honestly didn't understood completly) works in this case.

Comment: You could render Flux content with a FLUIDTEMPLATE cObject too, but in this case it might be easier to transfer variables directly, since the information is already available without using a data processor:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690804/how-the-get-the-parent-element-of-a-fce-in-fluid-powered-typo3

Answer (score 0):

Since the FLUIDTEMPLATE approach is a universal one, while the question might be closer related to Flux, here is a Flux specific way to hand over information to child records:

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Content/RenderViewHelper.html

```
<flux:content.render 
    area="NULL"
    limit="123"
    offset="123"
    order="'sorting'"
    sortDirection="'ASC'"
    as="NULL"
    loadRegister="{foo: 'bar'}"
    render="1"
>
    <!-- tag content - may be ignored! -->
</flux:content.render>
```

Just fill in some additional information to the `loadRegister` named `foo` to make it available via the getText method `register:foo` within the child rendering process.

```
loadRegister="{parentRecordType: '2'}"
```

and within your child record rendering use

```
10 = TEXT
10.dataWrap = My parent record is of type {register:parentRecordType}
```

Same goes for if conditions or switch objects based on the registered information.
And of course for Fluid based rendering of child records too.

Just use `<f:debug>_all</f:debug>` to get an overview of available registers and data.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Index.html#register

Answer (score 0):

Inside your flux content element template's `Main` section, use the `colPos` to find the parent's uid and `v:resource.record` to load its `CType` field:

```
<f:variable name="parentUid" value="{v:format.substring(content:record.colPos, start:'0', length:'-2')}"/>
<v:resource.record as="parentTypes" table="tt_content" field="CType" uid="{parentUid}">
  <f:variable name="parentType"><v:iterator.first>{parentTypes}</v:iterator.first></f:variable>
</v:resource.record>
```

This works because flux 9.7.2 uses "$recordUid * 100" as `colPos` for child elements.

---

Thanks to Robert Frenzel for this idea.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, everything is possible with TYPO3 and in a lot of ways. How are the content elements nested? From parent to children (templavoila) or from children to parent (gridelements)?

Comment: that's more a comment than an answer :(

Comment: Yes, sorry, should be a comment because feedback is needed to answer the question.